# Ubuntu 14.04 bootloader install failed

Tags: boot, system-installation, bootloader

Hi today I decides to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. Everything worked in the last moment, a message poped up saying that my bootloader install had failed and would not let me install it on a different drive so I continued anyway and on boot I get a black screen.

PS: I erased everything and installed ubuntu 14.04 five times.

There where no external drives but 1 internal hhd and an internal ssd

Comment: Were there any external drives attached to your PC while installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Check this answer and see if it applies to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to install bootloader](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127256/failed-to-install-bootloader)